# Using FindFit for Approximation Fourier Series

Tags: fitting, approximation

I am expecting to have a list of discrete points, which I would like to approximate using Fourier's series, then plot Fourier series approximation alongside with discrete points, then plot terms of Fourier's series individually and finally express the continuous function using Mathematica.

So far, I have come up with a code to use **FindFit** function which uses defined number of terms in Fourier's series. But I would like to use **n** number of terms which will equal to number of inputted data (discrete points).

Initial code uses 6 number of terms to fit discrete points using Fourier's series:

```
Clear["Global`*"]

data = {{0, 0.00056}, {0.01, 0.00147}, {0.02, 
    0.00197}, {0.03, -0.00006}, {0.04, -0.00002}, {0.05, 
    0.00538}, {0.06, 0.00594}};

dataLength = Length[data](*number of data points*)

(*Define a Fourier series of order n*)
f[x_, n_] := Sum[a[k]*Cos[k*x*2*Pi] + b[k]*Sin[k*x*2*Pi], {k, 1, n}];

(*Use FindFit to determine the Fourier coefficients that best \
approximate the data*)
fit = FindFit[data, 
   f[x, 6], {{a[1], 0.01}, {b[1], 0.01}, {a[2], 0.01}, {b[2], 
     0.01}, {a[3], 0.01}, {b[3], 0.01}, {a[4], 0.01}, {b[4], 
     0.01}, {a[5], 0.01}, {b[5], 0.01}, {a[6], 0.01}, {b[6], 0.01}}, 
   x];

(*Use the fit to determine the Fourier series that best approximates \
the data*)
fourier = f[x, 6] /. fit;

(*Plot the data and the Fourier series on the same graph*)
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red], Plot[fourier, {x, 0, 6.2}]]

(*Plot each individual term of the Fourier series on a separate graph*)


colors = ColorData[97, "ColorList"];
terms = Table[(a[k]*Cos[k*x*2*Pi] + b[k]*Sin[k*x*2*Pi]) /. fit, {k, 1,
     6}];
Plot[Evaluate[terms[[#]] & /@ Range[6]], {x, 0, 6.1}, 
 PlotStyle -> Table[colors[[k]], {k, 1, 6}], 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Table[Row[{"Term ", k, " of the Fourier series"}], {k, 1, 6}], 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]

Do[Print[a[k] Cos[kx2Pi] + b[k] Sin[kx2Pi] /. fit // 
   TraditionalForm], {k, 1, 6}]
```

I have introduced the variable `dataLength`, which is number of terms I would like to use for **FindFit**.

I tried to change the code in the following way:

```
(*Use FindFit to determine the Fourier coefficients that best \
approximate the data*)
fit = FindFit[data,    f[x, dataLength], 
   Table[{a[i], 0.01}, {i, dataLength}], 
   Table[{b[i], 0.01}, {i, dataLength}], 
   x];

(*Use the fit to determine the Fourier series that best approximates \
the data*)
fourier = f[x, dataLength] /. fit;
```

Unfortunately, I got several errors running the code, most of them due to **FindFit**.

```
FindFit::nonopt: Options expected (instead of x) beyond position 4 in FindFit[{{0,0.00056},{0.01,0.00147},{0.02,0.00197},{0.03,-0.00006},{0.04,-0.00002},{0.05,0.00538},{0.06,0.00594}},a[1] . An option must be a rule or a list of rules.
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Range `x` of your data is very small  `.01<x<.06` compared to the fulll period `2Pi` of your approximation! Is this intended?

Comment: This is just part of a data for testing purposes, actual data will consist of time with step interval of .01 seconds with up to possibly 10-20 seconds. The data is supposed to be taken from accelerograms.

Comment: Ok , you should think about the expected period of your data